# How to commission the GPON Voice Service (SIP) on ZXA10 C300 OLT?

Tags: configuration, voip, voice, telecommunication

How to commission the GPON Voice Service (SIP) on ZXA10 C300 OLT?

We have 1 unit ZTE brand [ZXA10 series C300](https://xponshop.com/collections/c300-olt) OLT and we want to know how to configurate the SIP Voip service on OLT side, can anyone help me on this, thanks.

Pls help to write down the step/procedures. It would be better if you can give an example case.